PHP Magic functions and empty() - weird behaviour
Can anyone explain me why empty() in this case returns true ?
It looks really weird :) and if I remove totally __set function then it works as I expect.
class testData
{
    protected $testData = [];

    public function __construct($dane = [])
    {
        if (is_array($dane)) {
            $this->testData = $dane;
        }
    }


    public function __get($xKey)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($xKey, $this->testData)) {
            return $this->testData[$xKey];
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function __set($xKey, $xValue)
    {
        $this->testData[$xKey] = $xValue;
    }


}

$data = new testData;
$data->example = '1234';
var_dump($data->example);
var_dump($data->example == null);
var_dump(empty($data->example));

Here above example: https://onlinephp.io/c/d7c131

empty determines whether a variable (or property) exists (and is not false-y.) Your object does not have a property named example. _"and if I remove totally _set function then it works as I expect" - because you are then implicitly creating an actual property by that name.

You set $data->example to '1234', and you never undo that, so $data->example isn't empty.

@KIKOSoftware actually for PHP $data->example is empty, you can see that on my example. C3roe exlpained it well , I checked this and I confirm his comment.
